# Does Delayed::Worker.new.work_off work jobs with a future run_at time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, delayed-job

I have a controller action that creates 2 background jobs to be run at a future date.

I am trying to test that the background jobs get run

```
    # spec/controllers/job_controller_spec.rb

    setup
    post :create, {:job => valid_attributes}
    Delayed::Job.count.should == 2
    Delayed::Worker.logger = Rails.logger
    #Delayed::Worker.new.work_off.should == [2,0]

    Delayed::Worker.new.work_off
    Delayed::Job.count.should == 0 # this is where it fails
```

This is the error:

```
 1) JobsController POST create with valid params queues up delayed job and fires
    Failure/Error: Delayed::Job.count.should == 0
    expected: 0
    got: 2 (using ==)
```

For some reason it seems like it is not firing.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use

```
Delayed::Worker.new(quiet: false).work_off
```

to debug the result of your background jobs, this could help you to find out if the fact that they're supposed to run in the future is messing with the assert itself. 
Don't forget to take off the "quiet:false" when you're done, otherwise your tests will always output the results of the background jobs.

Comment: Thanks! The tip was useful for me in figuring out a failing test.

Comment: I'm really glad it was useful for anyone besides me :D

Comment: Didn't work for me. Any other idea?